# How to fix uncaught exception: Header Signature

Tags: jquery, excel, uncaught-exception

I want to upload one excel document,read that document and write the excel document content in a table format in jquery i had achieved this with sample reference from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/d2atnbrt/5/). firstly thanks to that reference but here i was uploading my excel document from the system local storage it was showing error called **"uncaught exception: Header Signature: Expected d0cf11e0a1b11ae1 saw 504b030414000600"**. If i was uploading the document which i had downloaded from [here](http://www.whitehouse.gov/sites/default/files/omb/budget/fy2014/assets/receipts.xls) was generating the result successfully.I am not getting what was the error occurred i am suffering with last 2 days with this error 
Can any one tell me how to resolve this issue

This is my HTML code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/jszip.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/xlsx.js"></script>
        <script src=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xls/0.7.4-a/xls.js"></script>
        <title>Test Excel</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="load_excel();">
      <input type="file" id="my_file_input"/>
      <div id='my_file_output'></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my JS code:

```
function load_excel(){

  var oFileIn;
  oFileIn = document.getElementById('my_file_input');
    if(oFileIn.addEventListener) {
        oFileIn.addEventListener('change', filePicked, false);
    }

}
function filePicked(oEvent){

    alert('Function trigggered');

    // Get The File From The Input
  var oFile = oEvent.target.files[0];
  var sFilename = oFile.name;
  // Create A File Reader HTML5
  var reader = new FileReader();

  // Ready The Event For When A File Gets Selected
  reader.onload = function(e) {
      var data = e.target.result;
      var cfb = XLS.CFB.read(data, {type: 'binary'});
      var wb = XLS.parse_xlscfb(cfb);
      // Loop Over Each Sheet
      wb.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
          // Obtain The Current Row As CSV
          var sCSV = XLS.utils.make_csv(wb.Sheets[sheetName]);
          var data = XLS.utils.sheet_to_json(wb.Sheets[sheetName], {header:1});
          $.each(data, function( indexR, valueR ) {
              var sRow = "<tr>";
              $.each(data[indexR], function( indexC, valueC ) {
                  sRow = sRow + "<td>" + valueC + "</td>";
              });
              sRow = sRow + "</tr>";
              $("#my_file_output").append(sRow);
          });
      });
  };

  // Tell JS To Start Reading The File.. You could delay this if desired
  reader.readAsBinaryString(oFile);
}
```

Comment: had you found any difference in both excel files ?

Comment: Thanks man for your suggestion.It is retrieving data only from the excel file saved in the format of 'XLS' not in 'XLSX' by changing the file format to 'XLS' it is retrieving data perfectly.Thank you @HassanALi

Comment: I m happy for you .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can could code it so that it accepts both xlsx and xls. Based on your question and the documentation for [SheetJS/js-xlsx](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) I would suggest something like this:

```
function filePicked(oEvent) {
// Get The File From The Input
var oFile = oEvent.target.files[0];
var sFilename = oFile.name;
// Create A File Reader HTML5
var reader = new FileReader();

// Ready The Event For When A File Gets Selected
reader.onload = function(e) {
    var data = e.target.result;
    var cfb = XLSX.read(data, {type: 'binary'});
    console.log(cfb)
    cfb.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
        // Obtain The Current Row As CSV
        var sCSV = XLS.utils.make_csv(cfb.Sheets[sheetName]);   
        var oJS = XLS.utils.sheet_to_json(cfb.Sheets[sheetName]);   

        $("#my_file_output").html(sCSV);
        console.log(oJS)
        $scope.oJS = oJS
    });
};

// Tell JS To Start Reading The File.. You could delay this if desired
reader.readAsBinaryString(oFile);}
```

I tried it and it works fine. Let me know if I can help you with anything.

Comment: I got this error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: XLSX is not defined
    at FileReader.reader.onload"